# Need to find out when a user was suspended

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I can't see the information anywhere.
When I pull the users.List i only see if a user is suspended but not when the account was suspended. The information is visible on the user page in ADMIN, so the information has to exist somewhere.

Comment: I think, it's a limitation of the [`Users`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource-representations) resources in the Directory API. If you check the JSON, it doesn't return the date of suspension.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date of a user suspension by looking for the SUSPEND_USER event in the Admin-SDK Reports API.

You can use the "Try this API" feature here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list
and provide the following values (leave other blank by default):

- userKey: all
- applicationName: admin
- eventName: SUSPEND_USER

Further info: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-user-events#suspend-user